# How to display JSON data in laravel blade view

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting a JSON response

```
@foreach($logs as $log)
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{ $log->general }}
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    {{ $log->response_headers }}
  </div>
@endforeach
```

the response is not structured like this I have made is readable for now

```
General
{
  "host": "abcd-io.test",
  "path": "api/v1/companies/hello.com",
  "request_ip": "127.0.0.1"
}

response_headers
{
  "X-Powered-By": [
    "Express"
  ],
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
    "*"
  ],
  "Content-Type": [
    "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  ],
  "Content-Length": [
    "4857"
  ],
  "ETag": [
    "W/\"12f9-UhKH0rSAm7BiHIeW5pbrH1gphXs\""
  ],
  "Date": [
    "Sat, 20 Jun 2020 12:51:28 GMT"
  ],
  "Connection": [
    "keep-alive"
  ]
}
```

Controller

```
public function index() {
   $logs = Log::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

   return view('api.logs', compact('logs'));
}
```

what I wish is to display `host` and `abcd-io.test` separately

I tried using  `{{ $log->general['host'] }}` but it didn't worked

Comment: add your controller code

Comment: @TalhaF. updated the code with controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to and cast for the column in the model.

```
protected $casts = [
    'general' => 'array'
];
```

and hence in the view I can show it as

```
@foreach($logs as $log)
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{ $log->general['host'] ?? 'No host' }}
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "general" is a string, you might have to use json_decode($json) to convert a JSON string to an array and do something like this:

```
//Convert JSON to array
$json = json_decode($log->general, true);
```

Retrieve host

```
$json['host']
```

Comment: json_decode gives an error " htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"